# Rails not recognizing relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Having issues trying to set up the relationship in my database.

I have a user and some comments (1:N)

```
Class User .. 
  ...
  has_many :comments
end

Class Comment .. 
 ..
 belongs_to :user
end
```

When attempting to assign comments to a user through the console and I enter the following :
    user.comments 
I receive the following error

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column:
 comments.user_id: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE 
 "comments"."user_id" = 1
```

I have ran bundle exec db:test:prepare and my migrations as following

```
rails g migration CreateUsers ..... 

rails g migration CreateComments .....
```

I have tried db:schema:dump and migrating again but continuing to have the issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you added the `belongs_to` and `has_many` yourself, then you have to generate a migration for that to.

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_comments user_id:int
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `user_id` in comment model